# Creating a Dataframe by combining the list output

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, for-loop

Below is my code where  used a function Area to find the value AUC and Cutoff.

```
Area<-function(x){
library(ROCR)
library(Metrics)
log_predict <- predict(lr1,newdata = valid,type = "response")
log_predict <- ifelse(log_predict > x,1,0)
pr <- prediction(log_predict,valid$target)
perf <- performance(pr,measure = "tpr",x.measure = "fpr")
plot(perf)
a<-auc(valid$target,log_predict)
list(AUC=a,cutoff=x)
}
for (i in seq(from=0.1, to=0.2, by=0.01)){
  df<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, Area(i)))
  str(df)

}
```

I am getting my output as,

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num  0.779 0.1
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num  0.78 0.11
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num  0.779 0.12
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num  0.778 0.13
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num  0.776 0.14
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num  0.773 0.15
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num  0.77 0.16
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num  0.767 0.17
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num  0.763 0.18
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num  0.759 0.19
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num  0.756 0.2
```

I would like my output to be a data frame where the columns are AUC and Cutoff and the values are all represented in one dataframe instead of being in multiple dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lapply` to pass `Area` function for different values in sequence.

```
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(seq(from=0.1, to=0.2, by=0.01), Area))
```

In `purrr` we can use `map_df` which would make this shorter.

```
df <- purrr::map_df(seq(from=0.1, to=0.2, by=0.01), Area)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `sapply`

```
 sapply(seq(from=0.1, to=0.2, by=0.01), Area)
```